# Chrome Extension Taskbar Icon & Chrome Profile Thumbnail

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

My chrome extension manifest declares the use of icons as follows:

```
"icons": { "16": "images/icon16.png",
           "48": "images/icon48.png",
          "128": "images/icon128.png"
          },
```

and those icons look beautiful in the windows taskbar.  However!

The extension is designed to run even when the chrome browser is closed, but running in the background.  The design is that, when the user presses a certain hotkey, the extension creates a new window containing the extensions main UI.

When the user opens the UI (as explained above) while the browser is not actively running (i.e. only running in the background), the icon displayed in the windows taskbar is my beautiful icon and I am happy.  The same is true when the user has an active chrome window open, but for one extremely annoying difference, it displays the user profile image on top of my icon.

I'm not going to post a live example of my icon, but to show you what I'm talking about, see the following example with the default chrome logo:

[image]

Is there any possible way to resolve this, so that the icon always displays in full without any nasty profile in front of it?

I know that chrome generally treats the hangout application specially (i.e. it is allowed access to the taskbar icon tray directly), but its worth noting that the hangouts application always shows the correct icon unobstructed with the profile thumbnail.  That may be a clue.

Comment: @wOxxOm Your comment is simply incorrect.  There is no documentation explaining that chrome will use a favicon declared in a window (with its HTML saved in the extension's directory) as the task bar icon for that window.  It is therefore not true that "everything you can do is described in the documentation."

Comment: Okay, I get your point. See [the source code](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/chrome/browser/ui/views/frame/browser_non_client_frame_view.cc?q=DrawTaskbarDecoration&sq=package:chromium&dr=C&l=236) - profile overlay presence is hardcoded for some cases, which is apparently matches your scenario. As for Hangouts it's [created as an ASH window](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/chrome/browser/extensions/api/tabs/tabs_api.cc?q=ash_panel&sq=package:chromium&l=542&dr=C), which is different, evidently.

Comment: Haha--alright I'll take a close look at those two sources later today. I appreciate the help!